# is it really necessary to destroy dynamic components?

Tags: angular

```
const validReportTemplates = {
  default: DefaultTemplateComponent
}

@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) containerRef: ViewContainerRef;
  private _componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private _notificationsService: NotificationsService,
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _inspectionService: InspectionService,
    private _reportService: ReportService
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit (): void {
    this._loadReportTemplate();
  }

  private _loadReportTemplate() {
    const inspection: Inspection = this._inspectionService.inspectionForm.value;
    this.containerRef.clear();
    const factory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(validReportTemplates['default']);
    this._componentRef = this.containerRef.createComponent(factory);

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._componentRef.destroy();
    this.containerRef.clear();
  }
}
```

The ngOnDestroy() lifecycle hook in DefaultTemplateComponent is triggered anyway. It doesn't matter if I call destroy() and clear() in parents onDestroy hook. So is it really necessary to do this manually?

Another interesting fact is, that when in register a timeout in ngOnDestroy hook, the refrence to the dynamic loaded component is existant after destroy. Any ideas?

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this._componentRef.destroy();
  this.containerRef.clear();
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this._componentRef), 3000); // shows that DefaultTemplateComponent still exists
}
```

Comment: No. Just as you said, angular does the work for you and destroys all components when the element is removed from DOM. What you will have to do, is unsubscribe any custom observables during `ngOnDestroy()`, or else it can cause memory leaks.

Comment: @MikeS. thanks for information. But why is there still an reference to already destroyed component in the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

ngOnDestroy is useful for cleaning up data structures/pointers used in the component. For example, suppose on init you create rxjs subscribers for a number of observables. The destruction will not clean those up, they will stick around, which will cause issues if the subscription handler is expecting to make changes in the component (update state, change text, calculate some value, etc).